# Yii relations using variables of the active model

Tags: php, yii

I have two rows in one of my tables which look like:

```
id  product_id  target_product_id   description                    type
1   206587          456                     sdfgdfgdfg                  0
2   456             206587                  fgdgfhghfgfdsgfdghfghfsd    0
```

When viewing the model for the row with `id` `1` I wish to get the second row based on where the `product_id` and the `target_product_id` are inversed. So I made a relation of:

```
'linked_product_relation' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Accessory', '',
    'on'=>'linked_product_relation.target_product_id = product_id 
        AND link_product_relation.product_id = target_product_id')
```

However, it seems to only ever return `null`. I have checked that `link_product_relation` links to the table, and I get no SQL error, just a `null` return. If I use the relation with only `link_product_relation.product_id = product_id` though I do actually get a response, but only the row I am currently looking at. I seem to be missing something.

How can I get my desired output?

#### Edit

When I add a function to replace the relation:

```
function getTwinned(){

    $a=Accessory::model()->findByAttributes(array('target_product_id'=>$this->product_id, 'product_id'=>$this->target_product_id));
    if($a===null)
        return null;
    else
        return $a;

}
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify a foreign key (`''` in your code). Try something like this:

```
'linked' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Accessory', array(
    'target_product_id'=>'product_id',
    'product_id' => 'target_product_id',
)),
```

For more information also read the manual on this topic [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail).